# Анимированная печать строк из массива

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, циклы

Проблема состоит в том, чтобы вывести несколько строк из массива с анимацией в виде печати, а потом удаления и так далее со следующей строкой. С одной строкой проблем никаких не возникло, но когда я начал зацикливать функцию для работы с переменным количеством строк в массиве (пробовал и циклы и интервалы) скрипт стал вести себя не адыкватно (начинал печать не с той строки, одновременно и печатал и удалял, иногда даже разные предложения). Вот код для работы с нулевой строкой из переданного массива:

```
<span id="printer"></span>

<script>
function Print(data)
{
    if(typeof data.id === "undefined" || data.id == "")
    {
        console.error("Error!");
        return -1;
    }
    if(typeof data.phrases === "undefined" || data.phrases == "" || data.phrases == [])
    {
        console.error("Error!");
        return -1;
    }
    let elem = document.querySelector("#"+data.id);
    let phrases = data.phrases;
    let delayBefore = data.delayBefore || 500;
    let delayAfter = data.delayAfter || 3000;
    let speed = data.speed || 100;

    let dir = 0;

    elem.innerHTML = "&#9474";

    draw(phrases[0], speed, elem, delayBefore, delayAfter);
}
function draw(phrase, speed, elem, delayBefore, delayAfter)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        printing(phrase, speed, elem);
    },delayBefore);
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearing(phrase, speed, elem);
    },delayBefore + delayAfter + (phrase.length * speed));
}
function printing(phrase, speed, elem)
{
    let i = 0, text = "";
    let p = setInterval(function(){
        text += phrase[i];
        elem.innerHTML = text+" &#9474";
        i++;
        if(i == phrase.length) clearInterval(p);
    }, speed);
}
function clearing(phrase, speed, elem)
{
    let i = phrase.length - 1, text = "";
    let c = setInterval(function(){
        text = "";
        for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++) text += phrase[j];
        elem.innerHTML = text+" &#9474";
        i--;
        if(i == phrase.length) clearInterval(p);
    }, speed/4);
}

Print({
    id: "printer",
    phrases: [
        "You can take my heart, you can take my breath",
        "When you pry it from my cold, dead chest",
        "This is how we rise up",
        "Heavy as a hurricane, louder freight train",
        "This is how we rise up",
        "Heart is beating faster, feels like thunder",
        "Magic, static, call me a fanatic",
        "It's our world, they can naver have it",
        "This is how we rise up",
        "It's out resistance, you can't resist us"
        ],
    delayBefore: 1000,
    delayAfter: 2000,
    speed: 50
});
</script>
```

Comment: ну чет вы намудрили, интервалы не очищаете, запустив несколько раз `draw` у вас будет несколько запущенных интервалов. Ваша функция `clearing` очищает элемент, но не очищает интервал

Comment: @ThisMan, я учёл ваше замечание и снова обернул show() в интервал, поначалу всё было хорошо, но потом всё снова съехалось, на удалении превой строки. Цыклы for и while замораживают страницу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в своём решении пошли по правильному пути - разделили процесс на отдельные простые действия и все их пытаетесь запускать друг за другом. Но вместо интервалов проще решить это на коллбэках и таймаутах.

Вкратце всё работает так:

- запускам "рисовалку фраз" и просим её начать с первой фразы, а после окончания работы вывести некий результат
- "рисовалка фраз" ЛИБО рисует очередную фразу (делегируя это рекурсивно самой себе увеличивая индекс очередной фразы), ЛИБО понимает что фразы кончились и выполняет финальный коллбэк
- каждую фразу она рисует не сама, а делегирует в хэлпер - "рисовалку букв", который устроен (о, чудо!) точно так же! принимает на входе массив букв и индекс - с какой буквы начать; плюс коллбэк на случай окончания
- закончив рисовать буквы, "рисовалка букв" делегирует дальнейшую работу ещё глубже - "стиралке букв", которая делает тоже самое в обратную сторону и тоже в конце пути вызывает переданный ей коллбэк
- когда все фразы написаны, коллбэки начинают вызываться из глубин делегированных "рисовалок" вверх до самого начала и уже там вызывается наш рутовый коллбэк, который всё завершает финальным аккордом

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");

let drawPhrases = (phrases, phraseIndex, after) => {
  if (phrases.length > phraseIndex) {
    let chars = phrases[phraseIndex].split("");
    drawPhrase(chars, 0, () => {
      phraseIndex++;
      setTimeout(() => {
        drawPhrases(phrases, phraseIndex, after);
      }, 250);
    });
  } else {
    after();
  }
};
let drawPhrase = (chars, charIndex, after) => {
  if (chars.length > charIndex) {
    charIndex++;
    p.innerHTML = chars.slice(0, charIndex).join("");
    setTimeout(() => {
      drawPhrase(chars, charIndex, after);
    }, 250);
  } else {
    clearPhrase(chars, charIndex, after);
  }
};
let clearPhrase = (chars, charIndex, after) => {
  if (charIndex) {
    charIndex--;
    p.innerHTML = chars.slice(0, charIndex).join("");
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearPhrase(chars, charIndex, after);
    }, 250);
  } else {
    after();
  }
};
drawPhrases(["foo", "bar", "baz"], 0, () => {
  p.innerHTML = "end!";
});
```

```html
<p></p>
```

UPD.:

Можно сделать ещё проще в духе конечного автомата.

Запоминаем фразу, которую сейчас печатаем, индекс символа в ней до которого дошла очередь, и направление в котором идёт печать - вправо с добавлением букв или влево с их удалением (+1 - вправо и -1 - влево).

Остаётся написать универсальный способ как по этим индексам и направлению:

1. напечатать верный отрезок текущей фразы
2. изменить индексы для дальнейшего прохода по фразам и буквам (либо завершить работу если достигли конца)

А именно:

- `if (charIndex === chars.length)` - меняем направление отрисовки букв, если достигли конца фразы; с направления "печатаем" в сторону "стираем"
- `if (charIndex === 0)` - переходим к следующей фразе списка и снова меняем направление отрисовки для печати букв

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p"),
    phrases = ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    phraseIndex = 0,
    charIndex = 1,
    direction = 1; // +/- 1

(function draw(){
  let phrase = phrases[phraseIndex];
  let chars = phrase.split("");

  p.innerHTML = chars.slice(0, charIndex).join("");

  if (charIndex === chars.length) {
    direction = -direction;
  }
  if (charIndex === 0) {
    direction = -direction;
    phraseIndex++;
    if (phraseIndex === phrases.length) {
      return;
    }
  }

  charIndex += direction;

  setTimeout(draw, 200);
})();
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Хм, а о рекуррентном подходе я и не подумал. Да и писал в устаревшем стиле по собственной прихоти (слово function выглядит лучше, чем конструкция () => {}). Осталось теперь выбрать, какое решение использовать :)

Comment: @Евгений добавил в ответе второй вариант решения. он проще и понятнее.

Comment: Прекрасно! Реализация курсора, думаю, не вызовет трудностей, как и закцикливание. Признателен.

Answer (score 2):

```js
/**
  Воспользуемся всеми прелестями нового стандарта
*/


class Print {
  constructor({id, phrases, delays}) {
    // сюда можно добавить всякие условия и проверки
    this.delays = delays || [0, 0]; // начало и конец
    this.phrases = phrases || [];
    this.id = id;
    this.container = document.getElementById(id);
    // таймер анимации, сейчас реализовано так
    // что одновременно отрисовывается одна строка
    this.timer_ = null;
    this.running_ = false;
  }
  
  async start() {
    // очищаем перед стартом
    this.container.innerHTML = '';

    // так как наша анимая длится какое-то время
    // реализуем промис, который будет рисовать анимацию
    const phrases = this.phrases;
    this.running_ = true;
    for(let text of phrases) {
      // дожидаемся окончания каждой операции
      await this.draw_(text);
      await this.clear_();
    }
  }
  
  end() {
    clearInterval(this.timer_);
    this.container.innerHTML = '';
  }
  
  // типо приватные методы
  async draw_(text) {
    // сбрасываем предыдущий таймер
    clearInterval(this.timer_);

    // ждем нужное количество времени
    if(this.delays[0])
      await this.wait_(this.delays[0]);
    
    const chars = [...text];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.timer_ = setInterval(() => {
        // если отрисовали все буквы
        if(chars.length === 0) return resolve();
        
        this.container.innerHTML += chars.shift();
      }, 100);
    });
  }
  
  async clear_() {
    clearInterval(this.timer_);
    // ждем нужное количество времени
    if(this.delays[1])
      await this.wait_(this.delays[1]);

    const chars = [...this.container.innerHTML];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.timer_ = setInterval(() => {
        chars.pop(); // удаляем последний символ
        this.container.innerHTML = chars.join('');
        
        if(chars.length === 0) return resolve();
      }, 100);
    });
  }
  
  wait_(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
  }
}

const print = new Print({
  id: 'app',
  phrases: ['1234567890', 'абвгдежз', 'abcdefg'],
  delays: [1000, 500]
});
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons[0].onclick = () => {
  print.start();
}
buttons[1].onclick = () => {
  print.end();
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='app'></div>
<hr />
<button>Начать</button>
<button>Сбросить</button>
```

Comment: работает хорошо, только не повторяется и нет каретки, но думаю я с этими проблемами справлюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать готовую библиотеку Typed.js:

## Установка

With NPM

npm install typed.js

With Yarn

yarn add typed.js

With Bower

bower install typed.js

CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
```

или скачать на странице: https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

## Использовать так:

```js
var typed = new Typed('.element', {
  strings: ["", "First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
  smartBackspace: true,
  typeSpeed: 30,
  loop: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
<div class="element">
```

Comment: Хотелось бы реализовать самому, жалко потраченого времени, но библиотека указанные функции выполняет, хотя задержку задавать неудобно, но это уже лично моё мнение.

Comment: @Евгений из пушки по воробьям :) добавил ответ с нативным решением